# Unable to query/select data those inserted through Spark SQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight, apache-spark-2.3

I am trying to insert data into a Hive Managed table that has a partition.

Show create table output for reference.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                          createtab_stmt                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| CREATE TABLE `part_test08`(                                                                      |
|   `id` string,                                                                                   |
|   `name` string,                                                                                 |
|   `baseamount` double,                                                                           |
|   `billtoaccid` string,                                                                          |
|   `extendedamount` double,                                                                       |
|   `netamount` decimal(19,5),                                                                     |
|   `netunitamount` decimal(19,5),                                                                 |
|   `pricingdate` timestamp,                                                                       |
|   `quantity` int,                                                                                |
|   `invoiceid` string,                                                                            |
|   `shiptoaccid` string,                                                                          |
|   `soldtoaccid` string,                                                                          |
|   `ingested_on` timestamp,                                                                       |
|   `external_id` string)                                                                          |
| PARTITIONED BY (                                                                                 |
|   `productid` string)                                                                            |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                                 |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'                                                    |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                                            |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'                                              |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                                     |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'                                             |
| LOCATION                                                                                         |
|   'wasb://blobrootpath/hive/warehouse/db_103.db/part_test08'  |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                                                                  |
|   'bucketing_version'='2',                                                                       |
|   'transactional'='true',                                                                        |
|   'transactional_properties'='default',                                                          |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1549962363')                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Trying to execute SQL statement to insert records into the part table like below

```
sparkSession.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE db_103.part_test08 PARTITION(ProductId) SELECT reflect('java.util.UUID', 'randomUUID'),stg_name,stg_baseamount,stg_billtoaccid,stg_extendedamount,stg_netamount,stg_netunitamount,stg_pricingdate,stg_quantity,stg_invoiceid,stg_shiptoaccid,stg_soldtoaccid,'2019-02-12 09:06:07.566',stg_id,stg_ProductId FROM tmp_table WHERE part_id IS NULL");
```

Without insert statement, if we run select query then getting below data.

```
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
|reflect(java.util.UUID, randomUUID)|stg_name|stg_baseamount|     stg_billtoaccid|stg_extendedamount|stg_netamount|stg_netunitamount|    stg_pricingdate|stg_quantity|stg_invoiceid|     stg_shiptoaccid|     stg_soldtoaccid|2019-02-12 09:06:07.566|stg_id|stg_ProductId|
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
|               4e0b4331-b551-42d...|    OLI6|          16.0|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|            34.567|   1166.74380|        916.78000|2018-10-18 05:06:22|          13|           I1|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|   2019-02-12 09:06:...|     6|           P3|
|               8b327a8e-dd3c-445...|    OLI7|          16.0|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|            34.567|    766.74380|       1016.78000|2018-10-18 05:06:22|          13|           I6|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|2DD4E682-6B4F-E81...|   2019-02-12 09:06:...|     7|           P4|
|               c0e14b9a-8d1a-426...|    OLI5|       14.6555|                null|             34.56|    500.87000|        814.65000|2018-10-11 05:06:22|          45|           I4|29B73C4E-846B-E71...|29B73C4E-846B-E71...|   2019-02-12 09:06:...|     5|           P1|
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
```

Earlier I was getting error while inserting into Managed table. But after restarting Hive & Thrift services now there is no error in execution of job but **not able to see those inserted data while doing select query through beeline/program.** I can see partition  with delta files also got inserted into hive/warehouse, see below screenshot.
[image]

Also, I can see some warnings as below not sure its related to the error or not.

```
Cannot get ACID state for db_103.part_test08 from null
```

One more note: **If I use External Table then it is working fine can able to view data as well**.

We are using Azure HDInsight Spark 2.3 (HDI 4.0 Preview) cluster with below  Service Stacks.

HDFS: 3.1.1

Hive: 3.1.0

Spark2: 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below set commands while trying to insert data.

```
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

I have faced similar issue where i was not allowed to do any read / write operation, after adding the above properties I was able to query the table.

Since you have not faced any issue with external table, not sure if this is going to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried the same but its not helping.

Comment: After restarting Hive/Thrift services now not getting error but not able to see inserted data through beeline/program. updated question for the same.